# Problem with production build of spring boot and react app

Tags: build, war, tomcat8, production

I am working on a project which has its backend written in spring boot and UI written in react, the react UI code is clubbed into the maven project carrying spring code like

```
JavaMavenProject (Project Structure)
      ->src
            ->main
                  ->java (Spring boot code)
                  ->reactcode (UI react code)
                  ->resources
                  ->webapp
      -> test
```

I use plugins(snippet below) in pom.xml to build react code as well when i build my java code

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>Install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <nodeVersion>v14.15.0</nodeVersion>
                        <npmVersion>6.14.8</npmVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>install</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>npm build</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>run build</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <nodeVersion>v14.15.0</nodeVersion>
                <workingDirectory>src/main/reactcode</workingDirectory>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>Copy my react app into my Spring Boot target static folder</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/classes/static</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/reactcode/build</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Now when I test my entire application through Intellij things run fine, but when i create a war file to run it on "Apache Tomcat",even "index.html" is not loaded, I tried to debug this so I got below(image) mentioned problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWopD.png)

for which I **when I removed the starting backslashes** for these from the exploded war file in the webapp folder of Apache Tomcat(just to debug the problem)

```
<script src="/static/js/2.f62791a5.chunk.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/main.839bea33.chunk.js"></script>
```

so after changing above code to

```
<script src="static/js/2.f62791a5.chunk.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/main.839bea33.chunk.js"></script>
```

index.html along with chunk.js and chunk.css starting to show up like see below image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spA7w.png)

Now, aaahh.. when o tried to click on the links they are not working , I tried to check the network logs and also the server but no luck there as well.

Code of "package.json"

```
{
"name": "mapping-tool",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.32",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.12",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.2.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-autocomplete-input": "^1.0.15",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
    "react-bootstrap-table-next": "^4.0.3",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-editor": "^1.4.0",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-filter": "^1.3.3",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-paginator": "^2.1.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-flexy-table": "^1.3.6",
    "react-gif-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "react-select": "^3.1.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
},
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
        "react-app",
        "react-app/jest"
    ]
},
"browserslist": {
    "production": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
        "last 1 chrome version",
        "last 1 firefox version",
        "last 1 safari version"
    ]
}
```

}

code for "App.js"

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Mappings from './Mappings';
import Mapping from './Mapping';
import Test from './Test';
import Property from './Property';
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';        
import NavigationBar from './Components/NavigationBar';
import {Row, Col,  Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

function App() {

```
return (
    <Router>
        <NavigationBar />
        <Container>
            <Row>
                <Col lg={12} className={"margin-top"}>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/add" exact component={Mapping} />
                        <Route path="/edit/:id" exact component={Mapping} />
                        <Route path="/list" exact component={Mappings} />
                        <Route path="/tester" exact component={Test} />
                        <Route path="/property" exact component={Property} />
                    </Switch>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Container>

    </Router>
);
```

}
export default App;

code for "NavigationBar.js"

```
<Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
            <Link to={""} className="navbar-brand">

            </Link>
            <Nav className="mr-auto">
                <Link to={"add"} className="nav-link">Add System</Link>
                <Link to={"list"} className="nav-link">Mapping List</Link>
                <Link to={"tester"} className="nav-link">Add Mapping</Link>
                <Link to={"property"} className="nav-link">Property</Link>
            </Nav>
        </Navbar>
```

Problem statement in conclusion : I have spring boot and react app in one Maven Java project which i make a production build which I deploy on Apache Tomcat, Things run fine on Intellij but on Tomcat they are not running.

"sigh........"

I would appreciate any help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by doing following steps :

- using HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter
- setting  "homepage": "." in package.json

for point1 do this :

```
<HashRouter>
            
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Col lg={12} className={"margin-top"}>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path="/add" exact render={(props) => (
                                <Component1 {...props} restUrls={this.state.urls} />
                            )} />
                            <Route path="/edit/:id" exact render={(props) => (
                                <Component2 {...props} restUrls={this.state.urls} />
                            )} />
                            
                        </Switch>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>

        </HashRouter>
```